# Move selected element to the end

Tags: javascript, d3.js

We have HTML code

```
<select id="mySelect">
 <optgroup label="First group" id="firstGrp">
   <option value="One">One</option>
   <option value="Two">Two</option>
</optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Second group" id="secondGrp">
   <option value="Three">Three</option>
   <option value="Six">Six</option>
   <option value="Four">Four</option>
   <option value="Five">Five</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

I want to move `<option value="Six">Six</option>` to the end of `<optgroup label="Second group" id="secondGrp">`.

So, I select necessary element and remove it.

```
var secondGrp = d3.selectAll("#secondGrp option");
var six = secondGrp.filter(function(d, i){ return d === "Six")})
six.remove();
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to add it at the end of the `<option value="Six">Six</option>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37609694/4235784) by echonax you could just re-append the removed DOM element without the need to create and append a new one. This comes in handy if there are many attributes on this element.

```
d3.select("#secondGrp").append(function() {
  return d3.select("option[value=Six]").remove().node();
});
```

```js
d3.select("#secondGrp").append(function() {
  return d3.select("option[value=Six]").remove().node();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
 <optgroup label="First group" id="firstGrp">
   <option value="One">One</option>
   <option value="Two">Two</option>
</optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Second group" id="secondGrp">
   <option value="Three">Three</option>
   <option value="Six">Six</option>
   <option value="Four">Four</option>
   <option value="Five">Five</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

This make use of the fact, that [`selection.remove()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections#remove) will return the selection of elements which got removed. This is the use case it was designed for:

> however, you can pass a function to selection.append or selection.insert to re-add elements.

Answer (score 11):

I'm late to this party, but I'd like to add to this conversation the new `lower()` and `raise()` functions, introduced in D3 4.0. Its very simple:

> selection.raise()
>   Re-inserts each selected element, in order, as the last child of its
>   parent.

and:

> selection.lower()
>   Re-inserts each selected element, in order, as the first child of its
>   parent.

So, all you need to do is this:

```
d3.select("[value='Six']").raise();
```

Check this fiddle, you can click the buttons and see it going up and down: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/omk8r7dh/

The names here are a bit confusing, because "raise" will make "six" go down in the list, and "lower" will make it go up.

Comment: Nice answer! You beat me to it ;-) I thought about this solution when I started writing but forgot about it once I had finished my post.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the result: https://jsfiddle.net/bL6aavxr/1/

You can use an attribute selector to remove the value like this, no need for filter:

```
d3.select("[value='Six']").remove();
```

then you can "append" your desired option with whatever attributes and text you like:

```
d3.select("#secondGrp").append('option').attr("value", "Six").html("Six");
```